# How to use both Cron and Rate expressions for scheduling CloudWatch rules

Tags: cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to schedule a trigger for a AWS Glue job using CloudWatch schedule expressions. The requirement is to schedule the trigger to run every 3 hours between 8am and 6pm. I don't see any possible option of configuring this. Using the following expression, I can only schedule it between 8am and 6pm, but how can I configure the rate to be 3 hours instead of every hour?
cron(0 8-18 ? * * *)

The desired rate is to scheule it to run at 8am, then 11am, then 2pm, then 5pm.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
0 8-18/3 ? * * *
```